# Заполнение круга в прогресс баре с нужного процента

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть прогресс бар. Он идёт с 55% до 100%, но круг заполняется как будто с 0%.

Как сделать что бы заполнялся должным образом?

```js
let circle = null
const text = document.querySelector('.text');

function refreshCircle(percentage) {
  if (!circle) {
    circle = new ProgressBar.Circle(container, {
      color: '#000',
      // This has to be the same size as the maximum width to
      // prevent clipping
      strokeWidth: 4,
      trailWidth: 10,
      easing: 'easeInOut',
      duration: 6000,
      text: {
        autoStyleContainer: false
      },
      from: {
        color: '#ff9a89',
        width: 10
      },
      to: {
        color: '##ff9a89',
        width: 10
      },
      // Set default step function for all animate calls
      step(state, circle) {
        circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
        circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);

        const value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100 + 55);

        if (value >= 55 && value <= 71) {
          circle.setText(value);
          text.innerHTML = 'Адаптация плана Марафона к Вашему плотному графику';
        }

        if (value >= 72 && value <= 89) {
          circle.setText(value);
          text.innerHTML = 'Подбор подходящих Вам рецептов и тренировок';
        }
        if (value >= 90 && value <= 100) {
          circle.setText(value);
          text.innerHTML = 'Ваша индивидуальная программа похудения готова!';
        }

      }
    });
    circle.text.style.fontFamily = '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif';
    circle.text.style.fontSize = '3rem';
  }

  circle.animate(percentage);
}

refreshCircle(0.55)
setTimeout(() => refreshCircle(1.0), 3000)
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 2.14;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600,800,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А вы решили каждый вопрос по бару сюда писать? А может стоит изучить азы  js? Ведь прогресс-бар - это еденичный случай, а если потом понадобится делать что-то похожее, но родитель будет не прогресс...

Comment: @WalkMess стоит конечно, спасибо за замечание, конечно без знаний js, далеко не уедешь, поэтому спасибо, просто здесь то осталось уже немного, но обещаю это последний вопрос, если не кто не ответит, ну тогда уже сам

Comment: Попробуйте начать изучение с подходом Владилена. https://vladilen.notion.site/Roadmap-YouTube-0b917095c1ec424e9574c2ede36efab9

Comment: Теперь по вопросу. В математике мы обычно считаем ℅< как  0  и 1.  Вы передаёте 0.55, это правильно, но правильно ли вы пишите математическую формулу? Задумайтесь об этом.

Comment: @WalkMess спасибо за полезную ссылку посмотрю, изучу. Видимо нет, сейчас поковыряюсь, где там неправильная формула

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [документации](https://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shape/#setprogress) написано, как установить начальный % прогресса.

```js
const text = document.querySelector('.text');

const circle = new ProgressBar.Circle(container, {
  color: '#000',
  // This has to be the same size as the maximum width to
  // prevent clipping
  strokeWidth: 4,
  trailWidth: 10,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 6000,
  text: {
    autoStyleContainer: false
  },
  from: {
    color: '#ff9a89',
    width: 10
  },
  to: {
    color: '##ff9a89',
    width: 10
  },
  // Set default step function for all animate calls
  step(state, circle) {
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);

    const value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);

    if (value >= 0 && value <= 71) {
      circle.setText(`${value}%`);
      text.innerHTML = 'Адаптация плана Марафона к Вашему плотному графику';
    }

    if (value >= 72 && value <= 89) {
      circle.setText(`${value}%`);
      text.innerHTML = 'Подбор подходящих Вам рецептов и тренировок';
    }
    if (value >= 90 && value <= 100) {
      circle.setText(`${value}%`);
      text.innerHTML = 'Ваша индивидуальная программа похудения готова!';
    }
  }
});

function refreshCircle(percentage, from = 0) { // если не задано значение, начинаем с 0%
  circle.text.style.fontFamily = '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif';
  circle.text.style.fontSize = '3rem';
  const progress = from / 100;
  circle.set(progress);
  circle.animate(percentage);
}

refreshCircle(1.0, 55) // второй параметр - % начала прогресса
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 2.14;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600,800,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```